# Plot error bars on a horizontal bar plot in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart, confidence-interval, errorbar

How do you plot error bars, corresponding to 95% confidence intervals, on a horizontal bar plot in seaborn (i.e. bars from left to right, rather than bottom to top)?

Adding the `errorbar="ci"` argument does not work for me.

Comment: You probably have only one observation, as such there is no error. Additionally, the question does not contain a complete [mre], which should include data as formatted text.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/502379

Answer (score 0):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {"Group": ["A", "B", "C"], "Value": [5, 7, 9], "Error": [0.5, 1, 0.8]}

sns.barplot(x="Value", y="Group", data=data, xerr=data["Error"], errorbar=('ci', 95))

plt.show()
```